# How to dynamically change hasBackdrop property from MatDialog component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to control backdrop visibility from the dialog itself.

Ideally it would be to have it implemented like this, but there is no way (at least I didnt find it) to control backdrop from dialogRef:

```
export class MyDialogComponent {
 constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ServiceCaseFloatingEditorComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
  ) {}

  changeBackdropVisibility(){
     this.dialogRef.hasBackdrop = !this.dialogRef.hasBackrop;    
  }
}
```

any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created default class:

DialogComponent:

```
public static DEFAULT_CONFIG: MatDialogConfig = {
    hasBackdrop: true,
    backdropClass: FLOATING_EDITOR_BACKDROP_CLASSNAME,
  };
```

Outside usage:

```
this.editorDialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
      ...FloatingEditorComponent.DEFAULT_CONFIG
    }
```

then to toggle backdrop in DialogComponent :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.backdrop = document.querySelector(`.${FLOATING_EDITOR_BACKDROP_CLASSNAME}`);
}

  private showBackdrop(): void {
    if (this.backdrop) {
      this.backdrop.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }

  private hideBackdrop(): void {
    if (this.backdrop) {
      this.backdrop.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: It will be a bad user experience if the backdrop here and then away - controlled by the dialog itself. But if you need to handle it before the dialog will open you can do the follow:

```
 showBackdrop: boolean = false;

  openAlertDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent,{
      hasBackdrop: this.showBackdrop,
      data:{
        message: 'HelloWorld',
        buttonText: {
          cancel: 'Done'
        }
      },
    });
    this.showBackdrop = !this.showBackdrop
  }
```

Here I simple switch the `showBackdrop` boolean from `true` to `false` and so on. You can set this variable before you wanna open a dialog to set the backdrop manually.

Answer (score 0):

The only I can imagine is change the class of the cdk-overlay-backdrop using JavaScript

```
const backdrop=document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-backdrop');
const backdropLayer=backdrop?backdrop[0]:null;
if (backgroopLayer)
   backgroopLayer.classList.toogle('custom-class')
```